# Do nothing when item is dropped in a list using JqueryUI

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using JqueryUI to drag and drop to a sortable list. Suppose coll-selected-list is the list I want to drop on, I want to check if the current item I'm dropping exists in the list already. If it does, I wish to prevent the drop. Is this possible? My code is below:

```
$("#coll-selected-list").sortable({
        receive: function (event, ui) {
            //alert($(ui.item).text());

            var itemName = $(ui.item).text();
        if ($("#coll-selected-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")")) {
               //DO Nothing 
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [cancel()](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-cancel) method:

```
$("#coll-selected-list").sortable({
    receive: function (event, ui) {
        var itemName = ui.item.text();
        if ($("#coll-selected-list li:contains(" + itemName + ")").length) {
            $(this).sortable("cancel");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created this fiddle few days ago.

Check this - http://jsfiddle.net/ashwyn/nQWSw/

In the fiddle, if any item Div is already present in the sortable (droppable) div then it is reverted back. Maybe this is what you are looking for. Play around with it. I hope it will help. Cheers !!